# Approximating a distribution of functions instead of a single function?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, tensorflow, keras

It is easy for a neural network to learn to approximate an analytic function such as `f(x) = x^2` or `f(x) = x^2 + 1`.

I am struggling to learn a parametrized version of that (ie. `f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c`).

Given a context of 1000 `x` and `f(x)` pairs uniformly sampled from a quadratic with random `a`,`b`,`c`, I want to provide a target `x_t` and have the network predict `f(x_t)`.

My architecture is below. `input_1` is the context vector which consists of 1000 `x` and `f(x)` pairs. `input_2` is `x_t`, the position of the point I want to predict. `dense_6` is a linear layer with one neuron, supposed to represent `f(x_t)`.

[image]

To train, I have generated 100 random quadratics. For each quadratic, I generate 100 training examples. A training example consists of a random context (the 1000 points fed to the first network), and a random target.

However, I am unable to get this to work at all no matter what I do. The validation loss barely decreases. It either memorizes the training set and overfits or underfits.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this? What should I try?

Comment: are the parameters inputs too? without them it's impossible to predict

Comment: Why is it impossible to predict? If I were to plot 1000 points of a quadratic for you, you could easily approximate where a new point is.

Comment: Input_1 takes a vector of length 2000 ... 1000 x and their f(x) randomly sampled from a random quadratic. Input_2 is the x I want to predict the f(x) for, given the context in input_1

Comment: I guess an arbitrary degree polynomial. In a sense, I want it to learn to do polynomial regression on the context I give it, and can't figure out why it's not working although it should be straightforward.

Comment: I dont see why this should be straightforward, especially if your data is unbounded. Do you have errors in the data or do you assume that the Ys are exact?

Comment: I bound the x values between -5 and 5. The x and f(x) pairs I feed as context are exact.

Comment: Try a network with two layers and linear activations. It should work

Comment: I just did, and it does not. I will post my code soon

Comment: that was not a good advice, sorry.